# Connecting multiple monitors to PC or laptop: Graphic card outputs vs docking station

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, docking-station

Is there a difference between connecting external monitor directly to graphic card outputs and connecting the external monitors to docking station?

I read that new docking stations which uses USB 3 Thunderbolt technology do use in full capacity internal graphic card capabilities. But why do then graphic cards have more outputs if we can just use the docking station instead and we have the same results?

If we want to use **full** GPU power, resolution etc with the monitors that we connect with, which option should we use? Directly connect to GPU output or connect to the docking station?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most bandwidth and features, you will want to connect to the graphics card directly.  While USB 3 can allow for graphics cards, you are adding some latency and might not have as high of a refresh rate.

Comment: Is there a limit how many monitors I can connect?

Comment: I am not sure over thunderbolt.  Probably not a limit within reason.

Answer (score 1):

A docking-station that connects to a USB3 port can have display ports
to which one can connect monitors through the DisplayPort alt mode,
and that is indeed one way to add more graphical ports to the computer
than the ones that it came with.

However, the GPU inside the computer  is limited in the number
of monitors that it can support.
The usual limit is three, and only a high-end GPU can have more than that.

If the GPU limit is three and you connect more than three monitors,
you will find that only three monitors will be active. The others will
simply be non-functional.

In addition, you may be losing some small percentage of
performance (but not a big amount).

In summary, USB-C graphics ports do work. You will get better
graphics performance out of your laptop and their number is limited
to what the GPU can support, but they'll enable you to
add more monitors with reasonable performance.

Comment: So if I understdood correctly, if my GPU output is 3 I can connect only 3 monitors to it? 
If I want more than 3 monitors I need to use docking-station to add additional outputs but in that case I will lose some performance?

Comment: Not exactly. If your GPU supports 3, you can only connect 3 monitors. Only 3 monitors will work, no matter how many docking stations you add. The GPU will choose the 3 monitors to use and you can only change which 3 by disconnecting monitors that you don't need.

Comment: What is the point of using docking station then?

My laptop have just 2 outputs, 1 HDMI and 1 min DisplayPort. Does that mean that I can connect just 2 monitors into it? even if I use docking station?

Comment: What is your GPU?

Comment: NVIDIA Quadro (Laptop)

Comment: Which NVIDIA Quadro?

Comment: Is not clear for me what did you mean that if GPU have 3 outputs only 3 monitors will work even with docking station. In office i have 3 monitors which I connect to docking station plugged with USB 3 to laptop, even though my laptop has just 1 output.
Can you explain?

Comment: NVIDIA Qadro M1200

Comment: This is a mid-range GPU with 4GB on-board RAM. The maximal number of monitors doesn't appear in the specs, but there is a good chance that one more can be added via a dock.

Comment: And what is the purpose or benefit of having docking station? If no additional  "graphic outputs" can be added what is the purpose of having it?

Comment: You have the outputs. You might be able to add a third one with a dock.

Comment: Ok. If I have PC, in that case docking station makes no sense right? I can plug all directly in the PC tower. For laptop is maybe useful, I can keep all connected to the docking station... was that the main purpose for docking station then?

Comment: Docks typically extend the number of devices to be connected.